# Bootstrap 4 modal not working with anchor tag

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have tried this with bootstrap 3 and it worked fine. I'm trying the same thing with bootstrap 4 and the modal does not appear when i click the both buttons created through the anchor tag.

I have seen similar posts with the same problem, however theirs mostly relates to mistakenly using the . for a class reference opposed to # for ID. But this is not the case for me, i have also tried links to the actual modal.css and scripts to modal.js file but those have not worked either.

```
    <div id="updateCred">

      <header>Update Credentials</header>
      <p> Please Choose to Update Your Username/Password </p>
      <div id="updateCred">

        <header>Update Credentials</header>
        <p> Please Choose to Update Your Username/Password </p>

        <a href="#usernameModal" class="btn btn-lg btn-light" data- toggle="modal" data-target="#usernameModal">Update Username</a>
        <a href="#passModal" class="btn btn-lg btn-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#passModal">Update Password</a>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="usernameModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Change Username</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="passModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Change Password</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what it is.

You need to add the jquery and the bootstrap.js scripts

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script src="bootstrap-4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code have two bug! please close this tag:

```
<div id="updateCred">
....
</div>
```

Then please correct "data-toggle" into this line :

```
<a href="#usernameModal" class="btn btn-lg btn-light" data-toggle="modal" data- 
target="#usernameModal">Update Username</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title> Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

   <div id="updateCred">

    <header>Update Credentials</header>
    <p> Please Choose to Update Your Username/Password </p>
    <div id="updateCred">

        <header>Update Credentials</header>
        <p> Please Choose to Update Your Username/Password </p>
        <a href="#usernameModal" class="btn btn-lg btn-light" 
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#usernameModal">Update Username</a>
        <a href="#passModal" class="btn btn-lg btn-light" data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target="#passModal">Update Password</a>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="usernameModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button 
type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Change Username</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button
type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="passModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
               <button
               type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
  </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Change Password</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button
     type="button" class="btn btn-default"
    data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title> Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

   <div id="updateCred">

    <header>Update Credentials</header>
    <p> Please Choose to Update Your Username/Password </p>
    <div id="updateCred">

        <header>Update Credentials</header>
        <p> Please Choose to Update Your Username/Password </p>
        <a href="#usernameModal" class="btn btn-lg btn-light" data- 
      toggle="modal" data-target="#usernameModal">Update Username</a>
        <a href="#passModal" class="btn btn-lg btn-light" data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target="#passModal">Update Password</a>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="usernameModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" 
    data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Change Username</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
  data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="passModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" 
  data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Change Password</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
 data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```